# React Echarts Error for render custom Svg floor plan

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, echarts

I use react to visualise a Svg floor plan (heatmap) in reactjs.
However, it will return error

> cannot read properties of undefined (reading regions)

Code:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import * as echarts from "echarts";
import mapData from "./map.svg";

export default function Heatmap(){

const ref = useRef(null);

let mapInstance = null;

const option = {
    tooltip: {},
    visualMap: {
    left: 'center',
    bottom: '10%',
    min: 5,
    max: 100,
    orient: 'horizontal',
    text: ['', 'Price'],
    realtime: true,
    calculable: true,
    inRange: {
        color: ['#dbac00', '#db6e00', '#cf0000']
        }
    },

series: [
  {
    name: 'French Beef Cuts',
    type: 'map',
    map: 'testing',
    roam: true,
    emphasis: {
      label: {
        show: false
      }
    },
    selectedMode: false,
    data: [
      { name: 'Queue', value: 15 },
      { name: 'Langue', value: 35 },
      { name: 'Plat de joue', value: 15 },
      { name: 'Gros bout de poitrine', value: 25 },
      { name: 'Jumeau à pot-au-feu', value: 45 },
      { name: 'Onglet', value: 85 },
      { name: 'Plat de tranche', value: 25 },
      { name: 'Araignée', value: 15 },
      { name: 'Gîte à la noix', value: 55 },
      { name: "Bavette d'aloyau", value: 25 },
      { name: 'Tende de tranche', value: 65 },
      { name: 'Rond de gîte', value: 45 },
      { name: 'Bavettede de flanchet', value: 85 },
      { name: 'Flanchet', value: 35 },
      { name: 'Hampe', value: 75 },
      { name: 'Plat de côtes', value: 65 },
      { name: 'Tendron Milieu de poitrine', value: 65 },
      { name: 'Macreuse à pot-au-feu', value: 85 },
      { name: 'Rumsteck', value: 75 },
      { name: 'Faux-filet', value: 65 },
      { name: 'Côtes Entrecôtes', value: 55 },
      { name: 'Basses côtes', value: 45 },
      { name: 'Collier', value: 85 },
      { name: 'Jumeau à biftek', value: 15 },
      { name: 'Paleron', value: 65 },
      { name: 'Macreuse à bifteck', value: 45 },
      { name: 'Gîte', value: 85 },
      { name: 'Aiguillette baronne', value: 65 },
      { name: 'Filet', value: 95 }
    ]
  }
]
}

const renderMap = (myChart) => {

    /*const renderedMapInstance = echarts.getInstanceByDom(ref.current);
    if (renderedMapInstance) {
      mapInstance = renderedMapInstance;
    } else {
      mapInstance = echarts.init(ref.current);
    }
    mapInstance.setOption(option);*/
    myChart.setOption(option)
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(mapData)
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((svgText) => {
        echarts.registerMap("testing", { svg: svgText });
      });
    var chartDom = document.getElementById('beef');
    var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
    renderMap(myChart);
  }, []);

/*

  useEffect(() => {
    window.onresize = function () {
    };
    return () => {
      mapInstance && mapInstance.dispose();
    };
  }, []);  mapInstance.resize();
    
*/

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "50vh" }} ref={ref} id='beef'></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Svg file

```
<svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="591"
    height="373"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
    viewBox="0 0 376 237"
>

    <g transform="translate(-7.69,10.06)">

    <path
      
      d="m 536.375,106.46875 c 5.2885,14.34201 10.52945,33.1769 13.78125,43.21875 -0.0655,0.0771 -0.13181,0.1476 -0.21875,0.21875 l 16.5625,0.9375 10.5,-8.5 11,-17 -13.5,-18 -38.125,-0.875 z"
      stroke="#A5A5A5" 
      stroke-width="0.75"
      stroke-linecap="round"
      fill="#FFFFFF"
      fill-rule="evenodd"
      id="path3702"
      name="Langue" 
      transform="matrix(0.6362812,0,0,0.6362812,7.6936433,-10.065285)"
    />
    
    </g>  
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you displayed appears to be due to attempting to access (the `regions` properties of) an unregistered map.

In your code, you use the `options` object through `myChart.setOption(option)` on the main thread, so it's executed always *before* the asynchronous `fetch` `.then` chain;
so `myChart.setOption(option)` (that uses its `map`: `'testing'`) is called before `echarts.registerMap('testing', ....`.

Following you setting, you have to move the call to `setOptions` inside the `then` handlers:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('./map.svg') // "map.svg" is in the public directory
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((svgText) => {
            echarts.registerMap('testing', { svg: svgText });
            let myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('beef'));
            myChart.setOption(option);
       })
       .catch(e => console.error('fetch error', e));
});
```

You may also use `await` with `async` like in [these examples](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data/).

There some more details on how to avoid calling the `init` method on an already initialized chart/container. I included a skech of a solution for those in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-p2nfjb?file=src%2FApp.js) which is a simplified working version of your code. Feel free to fork it and use in further enquiries as a
reproducible example.

Comment: Your explanation is just so thorough. It's about asynchronous update. Also thanks for the tutorial on the await / async. :)